# Golang standard http package cors issue

Tags: http, go, cors

I'm using the built-in HTTP package on my server-side and I couldn't resolve the cors issue on my local machine. My server is sending JSON responses to the front-end.

I've tried setting headers in my handler func like below, but it didn't work:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

The post request front-end:

```
axios.post('localhost:8080/', {
  name: 'test'
  
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Server-side code:

```
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    fmt.Println("Server started at port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}

    func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
        content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        var file File
        json.Unmarshal(content, &file)
        // file name got here
        path := fmt.Sprintf("./posts/%s.txt", file.Name)
    
        textContentByte := readBlogFile(path)
        jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(textContentByte)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(jsonResp)
    
        fmt.Println(string(jsonResp))
    
    }
```

Comment: It's not easy to answer your question, because the problem is not well enough described. You've say you have a "cors issue", but what specifically are you doing, and where does your go server fit in, and what do you see? Perhaps you can include just enough information in the question that other people could reproduce the problem.

Comment: One possible cause of the error may be the use of `Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`. The `"*"` wildcard is allowed only for requests *without credentials*. If the request is sending credentials, then, instead of `"*"`, you have to specify the origin explicitly. You can extract the origin from the incoming request (the `r *http.Request` parameter of your handler). See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#directives).

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks for your response, I've added more details

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya What happens if you change `axios.post('localhost:8080/'` to `axios.post('http://localhost:8080/'`?

Comment: @mkopriva it didn't work

Comment: Can you attach your `Go` code to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers")` solved the issue.

Comment: Allowing `Origin, `Access-Control-Request-Method` and`Access-Control-Request-Headers` is pointless, since it's automatically added by the browser, rather than the client. Besides, because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header, allowing it is also pointless.